# Skipped X frames

Tags: c#, api, http, xamarin

I am writing an application in Xamarin and I am trying to call an API. I created a very simple API with one GET function called `GetString`. I tested the endpoint in Postman and I received a string (So, I think the API is working). Now I am having trouble trying to get the data in the Xamarin App. During debugging, the app does not appear to do anything when I call the api like `await client.GetStringAsync("GetString")`.

I see a message in the console that looks similar to:

`Skipped 374 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

I am using magic IP (10.0.2.2) in the Android Emulator.

Here is the code I am trying to use to make the API call in Xamarin:

In ViewModel:

```
public async Task GetString()
{

        var baseAddr = new Uri("http://10.0.2.2:58899/");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddr };
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        var returnedJson = await client.GetStringAsync("GetString");

}
```

API Controller on Server:

```
   public class ContactController : ApiController
    {

        [Route("GetString")]
        public String GetString()
        {
            return "asd"
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How can your eventhandler be of return type Task? It should be void. How can your GetContact() return type be "Contact" but your app expects a string? Why is the method called "SaveContact" but all it seems to try to do is fetching a contact from the server?

Comment: Because, I am lost in Xamarin and I tried lots of examples. Indeed, I did not pay attention for it.

Comment: It isn't clear from the code you provided what the problem is specifically that is causing you to skip frames but it is usually because you are running your API call on the main thread and it is taking a long time to return. This blocks the UI and causes it to miss frames. Where and how are you calling `GetString()`?

Comment: @AllenR I just want a simple application that communicates an api when I click button. What is the best way ?( I create a new command with GetString function in viewmodel and I use this command in view as command of button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Flurl Library found [here](https://flurl.io/) (installable via nuget) you could create a `ApiService` class and then call the `GetStringAsync` method from a button event handler or a command in your view model.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Flurl.Http;

namespace MyApp.Services {

    public class ApiService {
        public static async Task<string> GetStringAsync() {
           return await "https://api.com".GetJsonAsync<string>();
        }

    }
}

// In your code behind 
async void CallApi_Tapped( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    var returnedString = await ApiService.GetStringAsync();
}

// Or in a view model via a command
Command _doGetString;
public Command DoGetString => _doGetString ?? ( _doGetString = new Command( async () => {
    var returnedString = await ApiService.GetStringAsync();
} ) );
```

Here is an example showing how to call a public API at https://www.ipify.org/.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;

namespace MyApp.Services {

    public class IpAddress {
        public string Ip { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ApiService {

        public static async Task<IpAddress> GetStringAsync() {
            return await "https://api.ipify.org".SetQueryParam( "format", "json" ).GetJsonAsync<IpAddress>();
        }

        public static async Task CallGetStringAsync() {
            var returned = await GetStringAsync();
            Console.Write( returned );
        }

    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot showing the call complete.

[image]

Comment: Are you stopped on a breakpoint? The above code does not show that message for me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But, I am trying this and I am reciveing the same message. I do not understand android emulator, because I use magic ip with port (http://10.0.2.2:58899) I get status code 400. When I use localhost string with port I get "An error occurred while sending the request" message. And when I use my ip of pc I do not get any messages, but Skipped frames message apear again.

Comment: I just rewrote GetStringAsync function in your example. Body of function looks like:                 return await "http://10.0.2.2:58899"
                    .AppendPathSegment("GetString")
                    .GetJsonAsync<string>();
Where did I take a mistake ?

Comment: Does adding "http://" help? It is probably something wrong with the server or URL you are using not the C# code.

Comment: Oh sorry It is my fault. I copied wrong. But, I test with "http://". Exception message: Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException: Call failed with status code 400 (Bad Request): GET http://10.0.2.2:58899/GetString

Comment: Yea it has to be that you are not using the correct URL or the server is not set up correctly with that GetString Api endpoint. Try calling this api as a test `https://api.ipify.org?format=json`.

Comment: I see, but what is the correct URL? if I want to connect my localhost API from android emulator. I tried my  options.

Comment: I tested and I got the message: Flurl.Http.FlurlParsingException: Response could not be deserialized to JSON: GET https://api.ipify.org?format=json.

Comment: Call it like `"https://api.ipify.org".SetQueryParam( "format", "json" ).GetJsonAsync<string>();` You must include `using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;`

Comment: I got same message.

Comment: Updated my answer showing how to call that public api. After that you will need to figure out what url you should be calling for your system. You can probably ask a separate question about how to figure that out.